# How do I return value right in my HTML Page?

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel

I've been looking at other questions related to my problem however none seem to correspond to my exact circumstances.. I'm doing a TopTen Ranking with some datas about Webpages - Like whats the most IP's visiting your page, when was the last access, how many bytes... all this :)

now i have written a code that gives me all the bytes of the most 10 visitors of the page back.. and i want to return this result to my html page - that works but the output isnt really how i wanted it

this is my code:

```
$mb_bytes = array();
foreach ($topTenIp as $val) {
    $bytes_ips[$val] = shell_exec("grep $val /path/file.log | awk '{print $10}'");
    $add = array_sum(explode("\n", $bytes_ips[$val]));
    $add = $add / 1024 / 1024;
    $add = round($add, 2);
    array_push($mb_bytes, $add);
}
if($mb_bytes)
    arsort($mb_bytes);
```

now i returned this to my html page..

the output of $mb_bytes is :

```
Array ( [0] => 1.56 [5] => 0.61 [4] => 0.24 [1] => 0.16 [3] => 0.13 [2] => 0.08 [9] => 0.01 [6] => 0.01 [7] => 0.01 [8] => 0 )
```

but i dont want the output in my html be written in a row.. i want it like:

```
1.56
0.61
0.24
0.16
....
```

does anyone knows a solution for that? the part in my HTML looks like this:

```
            <tr>
                <th> Top 10</th>
                <th> Bytes</th>
                <th> Date </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($topTenIp as $ip[$i])
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $ip[$i] }}</th>
                    <th> here should be the $mb_byte variable </th>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

but i think the foreach in the HTML will do some problems too.. ( I'm working with the LARAVEL Framework

thanks :)

EDIT : now it looks like this !

```
IP 1.56 0.61 0.24 0.16 0.13 0.08 0.01 0.01 0.01 0
IP 1.56 0.61 0.24 0.16 0.13 0.08 0.01 0.01 0.01 0
IP 1.56 0.61 0.24 0.16 0.13 0.08 0.01 0.01 0.01 0
.......
```

but it should look like this:

```
IP 1.56 
IP 0.61 
IP 0.24 
IP 0.16
IP 0.13
IP 0.08
IP 0.01
IP 0.01
IP 0.01
IP 0
```

new edit:

my code :

```
 $mb_bytes = array();
        foreach ($topTenIp as $val) {
            $bytes_ips[$val] = shell_exec("grep $val /path/file | awk '{print $10}'");
            $add = array_sum(explode("\n", $bytes_ips[$val]));
            $add = $add / 1024 / 1024;
            $add = round($add, 2);
            array_push($mb_bytes, $add);
        }
        if($mb_bytes)
            arsort($mb_bytes);

        $resultArr = array();
        foreach($topTenIp as $ip){
            $byte = array_shift($mb_byte);
            $resultArr = array('id' => $ip, 'byte' => $byte);
        }
```

html:

```
                    @foreach($resultArr as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ $item['ip'] }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $item['byte'] }} </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

error message: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: can you tell me what is your problem here?

Comment: you have same number of ip and bytes?

Comment: i will edit my quesion

Comment: You're not opening/closing `<?php` tags in your `foreach` html section. That's also pretty unusual syntax. Why do you have @ symbols? Why are you using double curly brackets?

Comment: @Novocaine — From the question "I'm working with the LARAVEL Framework" so see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Comment: thats the Laravel Framework :) it allows me to use php with some other syntax.. @ is like: everything after @ is php - so @ = <?php ?>  ----------

and {{ }} is the same like echo " ";

Comment: @Quentin - right you are - I missed that line. I was expecting to also see that tag.

Comment: okay... we got that now.. does anyone knows a solution? i edited my quesion how it looks right know and how i want it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to first preprocess in controller your two `$topTenIp` and `$mb_byte` variables combine them in one single array `$resultArr` keep there for each item its `'ip'` and `'byte'`  then make loop over $resultArr array like this

```
@foreach($resultArr as $item)
   <tr>
      <td> {{ $item['ip'] }} </td>
      <td> {{ $item['byte'] }} </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

and you will have your output like this

```
IP 1.56
IP 0.61
...
```

**UPDATE**

you can combine your 2 variables with simple php logic

*IMPORTANT* if your `count($topTenIp)` == `count($mb_byte)` then you can do this to combination them

```
$resultArr = array();
foreach($topTenIp as $ip){
   $byte = array_shift($mb_byte);
   $resultArr = array('id' => $ip, 'byte' => $byte);
}
```

then pass and use $resultArr in template

Comment: i think i understand what you mean.. but how do i combine them? I'm still learning php :/

Comment: at the beginning i wanted to combine them because it would be easer for me to work with but i didnt know how..

Comment: i tried it.. but i think i did something wrong in the controller and the returning to view.. i will try some things out and will write you if i got it :)

Comment: or if i havent make it :D

Comment: i dont know what i did wrong but this havent works.. it just sais: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/laravel/logs/resources/views/domains/data.blade.php) ---- could you explain me another time what i need to do in the controller and how i use it in the HTML ? i thought i understood it but it havent worked with me..

Comment: my current output just puts every byte number like i want it.. but under the IPs.. not next to them

Comment: post above in your question new code from controller and from view which you tried so i will be able to help you

Comment: ok to make debug faster i created chat room in stackoverflow just open this link and start typeing - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97508/debug-chat-room

Comment: there is written i need 20 of reputation or something like that to get into the chatroom.. so i can just talk with you here in the comment box :) but i allready seen what you were typing there :)

Comment: Ah ok :D i didn't know that so 3) point output was null or number 1.56 ?

Comment: okay i did what you say :) and i've got it know :) i will post the answer in my quesion later - thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

try to assign the value to a variable not an array entry.

```
@foreach($topTenIp as $ip)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $ip }}</th>
                <th> here should be the $mb_byte variable </th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: how do i change its from a array to a variable? if i change it the variable will be a string and the output would be the same or not? I'm sorry, I'm still learning php...

Comment: np. In your foreach you pass each entry of `$topTenIp` to `$ip[$i]` <== this is the array I am talking about. Take a look at my code above. There you pass everything to `$ip` <== simple variable. Then you can use this to make your output in the foreach like so `<th>{{ $ip }}</th>` which is a string you can echo. hope this helps

Comment: should it be $mb_bytes[$i] too?